# In clickhouse, how to return null instead of throw exception when casting failed?

Tags: clickhouse

If it is failed to cast a string value to int, clickhouse will throw exception, how can I return null instead of throwing exception when casting failed? Thanks.

`SELECT CAST('a' AS Int32)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ClickHouse provides the set of function to solve it:

```sql
SELECT
    toInt32OrNull('a'),
    accurateCastOrNull('b', 'Int32')

/*
┌─toInt32OrNull('a')─┬─accurateCastOrNull('b', 'Int32')─┐
│               ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │                             ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │
└────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────┘
*/
```

---

See the full list of available functions:

```sql
SELECT name
FROM system.functions
WHERE name ILIKE '%ornull%'
ORDER BY name ASC

/*
┌─name────────────────────────────┐
│ accurateCastOrNull              │
..
│ toUInt8OrNull                   │
│ toUUIDOrNull                    │
└─────────────────────────────────┘
*/
```

Comment: Hi, @vladimir,  when I using accurateCastOrNull(22.32 AS Int16), it return NULL instead of 22,  it seems like this function is too strict to cast floating number to integer, how can I work round this issue?

Comment: @Henrik it needs to use *toInt16(22.32)*.